# Zeroing Out Orientation and Linear Acceleration of IMU

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to figure out how to zero out the orientation and linear acceleration of my IMU, so that when I launch it, the x and y values begin at 0, rather than at some value like orientation of 0.126.

Anything would help, but my code for using my IMU is here for reference: https://github.com/brianzhan/husky_robot_fork

Below is a sample of the message when I launch my um6.launch script, where orientation and linear acceleration don't begin at 0. It is necessary for me get it to 0 to fuse it with my wheel odometry data and other  tasks:

```
header: 
  seq: 456
  stamp: 
  secs: 1463184035
  nsecs: 667352940
  frame_id: imu_link
orientation: 
  x: 0.0279296576
  y: 0.1263548452
  z: -0.9905964737
  w: 0.0441436295
orientation_covariance: [0.01596195437014103, -0.0012914746766909957, -0.0005610909429378808, -0.0012914201943203807, 0.012185076251626015, 0.00017108242900576442, -0.0005610864027403295, 0.0001710832875687629, 0.011863413266837597]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.00319579559884
  y: -0.00106526519961
  z: -0.00106526519961
angular_velocity_covariance: [2.5e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5e-05]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: -0.03952058
  y: 0.4311336
  z: -10.28073997
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0036, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0036, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0036]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234330/zeroing-out-orientation-and-linear-acceleration-of-imu/) by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also faced this problem as IMU always gives non-zero values for angular velocity (and hence orientation) and linear acceleration even when it is not moving. I didn't find any built-in filter inside ros which could do this task of zeroing out the values when it is stationary. So, I ended up building my own simple filter in which I zero-ed out the values based on a threshold value. This threshold value was found through manual observations on imu.

---

Originally posted by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) with karma: 66 on 2016-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on 2016-05-15**:
Thanks a lot! May I ask, what you changed to zero out the values? I'm not sure what part of the code to alter

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-05-16**:
Find out the part of your code where it is publishing the imu message, and put a condition there that if the x,y,z value is less than 'threshold', then put zero values in the imu message instead of the original values.

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-05-16**:
I used rtimulib for my imu  so I put this condition in the while loop which you can find at the end of this file
https://github.com/romainreignier/rtimulib_ros/blob/master/src/rtimulib_ros.cpp

**Comment by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on 2016-05-17**:
Thank you so much!

**Comment by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on 2016-05-17**:
I actually couldn't figure out where/how the while or if condition there checks for threshold of zeros values in the code you linked?

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-05-17**:
The link I provided contains the original code. I put an If condition inside the while loop just before the line imu_pub.publish(imu_msg). Following is the If condition.

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-05-17**:
If (imu_msg.angular_velocity.z <= 0.009) {
imu_msg.angular_velocity.x = 0;
imu_msg.angular_velocity.y = 0;
imu_msg.angular_velocity.z = 0;
imu_msg.linear_acceleration.x = 0;
imu_msg.linear_acceleration.y = 0;
imu_msg.linear_acceleration.z = 0;
}

**Comment by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on 2016-05-17**:
Got it, thank you so much for the help!

**Comment by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on 2016-05-17**:
I just tried this: for me, it only artificially zeros out the angular velocities? Basically, when the condition is satisfied, the items will be published as 0, but when it is not, the values will be published incorrectly again?